# Session State removing and adding overhead

Tags: asp.net, session-state

The following is how I usually handle objects in Session State, I have a const string as the session name and then have a property with a get and set for the Object.

What I was wondering was if the 'Session.Remove()' call was necessary (to keep things clean and tidy) and if there was significant overhead and doing this removal.

I have the Session.Remove there basically because it makes me feel better (OCD i know), and makes me feel like the session is cleaner, but I would like to know if it isn't needed.

```
private const string sesMyObject = "{C2CC72C3-1466-42D4-8579-CAA11F261D55}";
public MyObject MyObjectProperty
{
    get
    {
        return Session[sesMyObject] as MyObject;
    }
    set
    {
        Session.Remove(sesMyObject);
        Session.Add(sesMyObject, value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
per the answers below i have changed my properties to the following:

```
private const string sesMyObject = "{C2CC72C3-1466-42D4-8579-CAA11F261D55}";
public MyObject MyObjectProperty
{
    get
    {
        return Session[sesMyObject] as MyObject;
    }
    set
    {
        Session[sesMyObject] = value;
    }
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to be safe, try converting the object to a IDisposable, and if it succeeds, call Dispose.

```
IDisposable sesDispObj =  Session[sesMyObject] as IDisposable;
if (sesDispObj != null)
   sesDispObj.Dispose();
```

Other than that,

```
 Session[sesMyObject] = value
```

is pretty much the same as

```
 Session.Remove(sesMyObject);        
 Session.Add(sesMyObject, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's overkill. Refering [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.add.aspx)

> If the name parameter refers to an
>   existing session state item, the
>   existing item is overwritten with the
>   specified value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Session[sesMyObject] = value;
```

is shorter, simpler to read, and should have slightly better performance, but unless this code is being repeated very many times in succession, it shouldn't make a difference.